# Azure file service in production?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

This is not a technical query, but rather information if anyone has an idea.
When does MS plan to have Azure File Service ready to use for production as it's currently in preview.

I had a specific requirement and Azure File service is perfect fit, but have been suggested to not use it for production environments while in preview

Comment: You're right. There's no information about when this service will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure File service went 'general availability' on Sept 29, 2015.

GA release links and some tech docs below.

- Overview - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/
- How to use - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa

Answer (score 0):

Like @ThiagoCustodio said, no timing information for all the Azure preview features actually.

From our experience, even the preview version won't cause much problem in production environment, maybe our scenario is not **that** complex.

We are using `Redis Cache` and `Azure File` service, both are in preview.